# How to get the graphical layout Window back in Eclipse for Android Application Design?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin

I dont know what happend, but i lost the Graphical Layout Window of the XML Layout that we are using in Eclipce to design the Android Application.
I want that Design window back.
 I can see the xml code and every thing. . . But i want the Design Editor that is available as by default in the Eclipse after integration of the Android in it.

So how to get it back ???

Comment: Make sure they are not minimized to the right and left of the code/preview window

Comment: No, If i open the anoterh project xml file then i can able to see that Graphical Window. But if i open currently working Project xml then it cant open that window.

Comment: Another simple check.  Make sure the file name ends with .xml Eclipse will not recognize it as a layout file without the xml extension.

Comment: The same happened to me when I imported an Android project into Eclipse. Your answer made it work, thanks.

Comment: @Alesqui: Welcome Alesqui. Enjoy.  :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No one has answered my question, but by searching on Eclipse I got the answer:

I have to right click on the XML code layout and then select Open With Layout Editor. It will show me the Graphical Layout Editor for my Application and now I am able to see the graphical view on the XML layout files.

Answer (score 12):

Do you not see the "Graphical Layout" tab on the bottom of the open xml file?

Comment: yes, dont know why but i am not able to see that layout and only see the xml code. And after some time i got the sollution of it. Please read my answer for the sollution.

Answer (score 10):

Just follow this pattern : Package Explorer ---> res --> Layout ---> activity_main.XML Open activity_main.XML

Comment: Thanks for cutting to the chase on this.  How frustrating!

Answer (score 5):

if you are using the dark juno color theme the tabs at the bottom don't show up.

change back to one of the original color themes and poof they're back.

Comment: I had same problem with moonrise theme. Too bad, I liked it.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse,just click check for updates and after that it will restart the eclipse and now u can see the graphical layout,the problem was in ADT plugin only.

Comment: Please see the answer i have given. there is no need of update the eclipse. Just follow my answer and you will get the Graphical Layout in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open all the xml files in layout editor, go to **Preferences->general->editor->FIle associations**
Change the default editor in the selections

Comment: or use right click on resource select open with-> Legacy Android Layout Editor

Answer (score 1):

For me, after reading endless non-viable solutions (including remove and re-import the project, click the 'open with...' menu and the like) the solution was stupidly simple.  I was opening the project with the standard Eclipse studio.  The solution was to open Eclipse via the ADT bundle directory, that is the version of the Eclipse studio packaged and installed with the Android ADT.  Using THAT shortcut to Eclipse, an Android project opens and runs (and edits) as a native Android project using appropriate Android tools.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to right-click and select open DEFAULT Editor...Then on bottom of editor two tabs will change on the lower right. Click on Graphical Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved installation ADT http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

This contain all preview layout and XML editor

Answer (score 0):

You can also, in the project explorer on the left, go to res, layout and double click on activity_main.xml