# How can I open the graphical layout tab for a new xml file in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

To preface, I have already read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708574/how-to-get-the-graphical-layout-window-back-in-eclipse-for-android-application-d).

In eclipse, after creating a new xml file and right clicking on it. I select "Open With" > "Legacy Android Layout Editor".

The view it actually gives me is not the Graphical Layout, but just the regular "code". "Legacy Android Layout Editor" is the only option that I've found in preferences. I then tried updating eclipse, but this doesn't resolve the issue. Does anyone know a way to get the graphical layout back?

Answer (score 0):

Just to motivate elaboration on this. Did you create a new **android layout xml** or a regular xml? Also, I have several options when right-clicking the android layout xml and selecting "open with" --> "other". Under "Internal editors" I have four Android xml editors: Binary, Common, Export and Manifest. I use the Android Common XML editor. Check your sdk version, perhaps theres an update available. [Official Android sdk download link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: I guess I should be more clear. I did create a new android layout xml.