# Eclipse errors while editing XML Layout file

Tags: android, eclipse-juno

When I'm in my XML files trying to edit them in the code tab eclipse starts moving other lines of code to wherever my cursor goes. The changes never actually stay if I go to the graphic view and then back everything is back to normal and I don't even have the option to save the changes that keep inserting themselves in there. This is causing me to only be able to make changes from the graphic view tab which is terrible any ideas?

Comment: may be it helpful to you, have you look on this so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708574/how-to-get-the-graphical-layout-window-back-in-eclipse-for-android-application-d

Comment: i am also facing same problem and i has been always restart xml or clean the project. it woks for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the eclipse known error. Just close the file and reopen it again. It will work for you.

If this don't work then just restart the eclipse once.

Comment: with the udate that problem quit

Answer (score 1):

You can usually fix this by doing Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V. For whatever reason, copying and pasting the entire contents of the XML always fixes this issue for me.